# Self-intersection number of a loop on a surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geometric-topology, covering-spaces

Let $M$ be an orientable surface$($without boundary$)$, **possibly non-compact**. Let $\alpha\in \pi_1(M)$ be a primitive element i.e. $\alpha$ is not a proper power of some other element.  Let $f:\Bbb S^1\to M$ be any loop representing $\alpha$. Consider the lifting problem [image]

Here, $M_\alpha$ be the cover corresponding to the subgroup $\langle\alpha\rangle$ of $\pi_1(M)$ and $\widetilde M$ be the universal cover of $M$. Also, all unleveled maps are covering maps.

Note that $\pi_1(M)$ acts on $\widetilde M$ via covering transformations, and $M_\alpha$ be an open annulus$($any open connected surface with a finitely generated fundamental group is homeomorphic to the interior of a closed surface$)$.

> $\textbf{Problem 1:}$ Consider two sets $$\mathscr A_f:=\big\{g\in
>  \pi_1(M):\text{ the map } \Bbb R\xrightarrow{g\cdot \ell}\widetilde
>  M\to M_\alpha\text{ runs from one end to other of the open annulus
>  }M_\alpha\big\},$$ $$\mathscr B_f:=\big\{(z,w)\in \Bbb S^1\times\Bbb
>  S^1:z\not= w\text{ and   }f(z)=f(w)\big\}$$ Is the cardinality of
> $\mathscr B$ **two-times** the cardinality of $\mathscr A$, i.e. $|\mathscr A_f|=\frac{1}{2}|\mathscr B_f|$?

> $\textbf{Problem 2:}$ Give a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that
> $\alpha$ can be represented by a shortest loop $f^\#:\Bbb S^1\to M$,
> i.e. $f^\#$ has the minimum length in its free homotopy class. Is
> $|\mathscr A_f|\geq |\mathscr A_{f^\#}|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem one, the answer is "no" as there may be "bigons".  The pair of intersections forming the bigon contribute to $B_f$ but not to $A_f$.

For problem two, the answer is "yes" as the shortest representative has no bigons.

A version of this is discussed in the "Primer on mapping class groups" by Farb and Margalit under the name "the bigon criterion".

Comment: Another question does every(**compact or non-compact**) surface without boundary has the property: there is a Riemannian metric on the surface such that **every non-trivial** element of the fundamental group can be represented by a **shortest loop**.

Comment: How do I relate the words "shortest", "bigons', "$\mathscr A_f$?

Comment: For your first question in the comments - there is always a constant curvature metric that does the job.  For your second question in the comments - I recommend you look at the reference I suggested.

Comment: Sorry, but any reference for "there is always a constant curvature metric that does the job" I am asking because most of the Riemannian geometry book deals with the compact case. Also, I have read the proof bigon-criterion(second proof), and there is no link(as far as I can see) it with the **shortest**.

Comment: The compact and non-compact cases are dealt with in the same way - this is an application of the uniformisation theorem.  As for your second question - prove that a shortest representative cannot have bigons.  [Hint - draw a picture.]